# What is the pun in 猥シャツ?

Tags: vocabulary, puns

Could someone explain why 猥シャツ is defined as "obscene shirt (pun)"? I don't understand how this is a pun.

> 猥シャツ 【わいシャツ】 (n) (See Ｙシャツ) obscene shirt (pun)

Source: [http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1MUEワイシャツ](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1MUE%E3%83%AF%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A3%E3%83%84)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pun is that the kanji 「猥」, read 「わい」, means "obscene", whereas 「ワイシャツ」 means "dress shirt". The [portmanteau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) 「猥シャツ」 therefore means "obscene shirt".

Comment: Is `ワイ` -> `Y` referring to the V formed by the neck and the | where the buttons are (you can tell I'm not in the shirt business)?

Comment: @Karl: I'm pretty sure it's just because of the English pronunciation of the letter "Y".

Comment: I've never heard a dress shirt called a "Y shirt" in English. Is that a UK thing?

Comment: @Karl: It's never, ever called a "Y shirt" in English.

Comment: So what I was asking is, why do they call it that in Japanese?

Comment: Probably because 「わい」 sounds like "Y".

Comment: ... I don't think you understand. Why is 「ワイシャツ」 used to mean "dress shirt" (it would appear to be some kind of wasei-eigo), and not, say, 「エクスシャツ」?

Comment: If 大辞林　is to be trusted, it actually comes from "white shirt", not "Y shirt". How it got from ホワイト　to ワイ　is not explained. Maybe by analogy with "T shirt"?

Comment: @rdb If you are following that, then it should be clear that in English, the counterpart to `ホワイト` is rather pronounced like `ワイ`; `ホ` is aspiration, and `ト` is often not pronounced in English prnounciation.

Comment: rdb's claim about the origin may (or may not) be correct, but in present usage, it is not necessarily white. Karl's speculation is right in mentioning the shape, but I think the general understanding of Japanese people is that it is referring to the shape when the sleeves are held upward.

Comment: As I said, it's 大辞林's claim, not mine. If it is true, though, the "Y shirt" theory becomes a false folk etymology. The puzzle is explaining why ホワイトシャツ　changed to ワイシャツ　while things like ホワイトハウス didn't become ワイハウス. I'm not an etymologist, though; I just play one on this board.　(笑)

Comment: @sawa The usage is said to be as ancient as Meiji period, and it becomes what it is today due to 訛り(namari). By the way, another interesting/funny false folk etymology would be ワイシャツ＝ワイ(俺)のシャツ "my shirt". It could be fun to tell them as jokes to nieces and nephews! DISCLAIMER: I don't condone telling lies as a joke! It is against my belief to joke using a lie!

Answer (score 3):

Look up the word 猥褻. It will all become clear.

猥褻 = わいせつ = obscenity

Comment: I couldn't find 褻 in my usual reference, and trying it with Google gives primarily Chinese rather than Japanese results.

Comment: I think the word is normally written in hiragana. You can limit Google searches by language. If you limit your search to Japanese, this page should be among the first hits:
http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/わいせつ
Alternatively:
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/81626/m0u/猥褻/